# Select a specific group of a grouped dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df.index = df['Date']
df.groupby([df.index.month, df['Category'])['Amount'].sum()

Date   Category     Amount     
1      A            -125.35
       B            -40.00
                    ...
12     A            505.15
       B            -209.00
```

I would like to report the sum of the Amount for every Category B like:

```
Date   Category     Amount     
1      B            -40.00
                    ...
12     B            -209.00
```

I tried the `df.get_group` method but this method needs tuple that contains the Date and Category key. Is there a way to filter out only the Categories with B?

Comment: `df.query('Category == "B"').groupby([df.index.month, df['Category'])['Amount'].sum()` ?

Comment: This results in an Error: `ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`

Comment: `df.query('Category == "B"').groupby([df['Date'].dt.month, df['Category'])['Amount'].sum()`, now you can also skip your line of settings the new index

Comment: Alright but I still get the same error message

Comment: I see, it's becaue `df['Date'].dt.month` points to original index. Try `cat_b = df.query('Category == "B"')` Then after that `cat_b.groupby([cat_b.dt.month, 'Category'])['Amount'].sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IndexSlice`:

```
# groupby here
df_group = df.groupby([df.index.month, df['Category'])['Amount'].sum()

# report only Category B
df_group.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'B'],:]
```

Or query:

```
# query works with index level name too
df_group.query('Category=="B"')
```

Output:

```
               Amount
Date Category        
1    B          -40.0
12   B         -209.0
```

Answer (score 0):

apply a filter to your groupby dataframe where Category equals B

```
filter=df['Category']=='B'
df[filter].groupby([df.index.month, df['Category'])['Amount'].sum()
```